# put a script in the separate module

Tags: javascript

please help to fix [script](http://jsfiddle.net/H2qDm/1/)

I added some buttons functionality. then tried to put all the js-code in a separate scope. that is, put it into a design

```
var testModule = (function () {
 
}) (this);
```

the resulting code has stopped working

Comment: Don't you think you should upload a working jsfiddle with all the included libraries ? (what is `observerable` ? which FW?) ? Also add the library tag here .

Comment: jsfiddle didn't seem to be working for me but anyways
I would suggest adding jquery to your scripts and put all your javascript code in a doc ready funktion something like `$( document ).ready(function() {
  // your code goes here
});`
so yeah this should work if your js code worked before moving it to another file. don't forget to add the jquery library.
Good luck

Comment: @photowalker I believe it's knockout or backbone

Comment: First of all, you need to return _something_. Second, using `var xxx;` won't make `.xxx` available on your result, you need to add it to your result.

Comment: sorry. here is the code connected with jquery http://jsfiddle.net/H2qDm/2/

Comment: Does this do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/H2qDm/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't return anything from the function, so the value of `testModule` is `undefined`.

Then you tried to access `testModule.observable` which is the same as `undefined.observable`, which is an error.

(<s>Also you need to select jQuery in your fiddle.</s> -- fixed by OP, see comment to question.)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the argument!

Watch this snippet:

```
var foo = 'foo';


(function(fooAliasToBeUsedInsideTheClosure){
    console.log(fooAliasToBeUsedInsideTheClosure);
}(foo))


(function(){
    console.log(fooAliasToBeUsedInsideTheClosure);
}(foo))
```

The first attempt to print 'foo' in the console works properly. But second fails, because there's no argument in closure to match with foo var. Then it considers foo = undefined within its code.

In your example, this situation it's particularly extreme because you are forcing the asignment 'this = undefined'.

So, try to fix that at first instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return at the end of the function:

```
var testModule = (function () {


   return {
              observerable : observerable
          };
}) (this);
```